# How to call data from another table in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, one for "models" and another to "votes", I want to take the model name by the vote (Vote Field = model id)

Votes Migration Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('votantes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome', 100);
        $table->string('email', 60)->unique();
        $table->integer('voto')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();         

        $table->foreign('voto')->references('id')->on('candidatas')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}
```

Votes Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Candidata;

class Votante extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'email', 'voto'];

    public function candidata() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Candidata');
    }
}
```

Models Migration Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('candidatas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nome', 100);
        $table->string('clube', 60);
        $table->string('foto', 100);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My Controller

```
public function votacao()
{
    $linhas = Votante::orderBy('nome')->get();
    // dd($linhas);

    return view('votacao', ['linhas' => $linhas]);
}
```

My blade file where i want to show the vote member, email and the model_name

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Cód Votante</th>
        <th>Nome Votante</th>
        <th>Modelo Escolhida(Cód)</th>
        <th>e-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach ($linhas as $linha)
    <tr>
      <td> {{ $linha->id }} </td>
      <td> {{ $linha->nome }} </td>
      <td> {{ $linha->candidata->nome }} </td>
      <td> {{ $linha->email }} </td>

    @endforeach
```

I want to record the votes entry, and from that data display in another window the name of who voted, the email, and the name of the model.

Currently the whole listing works, the only impediment is in displaying the name of the template, not the "id" registered in the votes table.

Comment: Can you show Candidata model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent model does not use id as its primary key, or you wish to join the child model to a different column, you may pass a third argument to the belongsTo method specifying your parent table's custom key

```
public function candidata() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Candidata','voto','id');
}
```

[Check this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#Defining%20The%20Inverse%20Of%20The%20Relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be like:

```
public function votacao()
    {

        $linhas = Votante::with('candidata')->orderBy('nome')->get();
        // dd($linhas);
        return view('votacao', ['linhas' => $linhas]);

    }
```

Comment: I try this, but show the same error.
"Trying to get property 'nome' of non-object (View: C:\Users\maico\Downloads\fenadoce\Atividade2Laravel\resources\views\votacao.blade.php)"
Thanks anyway.

Comment: maybe that one does not have a candidata ?

Comment: In your controller try returning the data without the view to see what happens, like this: `return $linhas;`